# Avoiding a static member function in c++ when using a callback interface from C

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I would like to access the data within this member function that is static.  Right now the member function is static so that I can use it with a third party API written in C that has typdef function pointer for callback purposes.  Based on the info below, what is the best way to get around the need to create a static function in order to use the data from the following function member within other member functions of my class that are non-static.  Maybe there is a way to still use this static function but still overcome the inability to mix static with non-static variables.  My code does works as is but with no ability to access the data in the following callback function.

```
void TextDetect::vtrCB(vtrTextTrack *track, void *calldata) /*acts as a callback*/
{
/*specifically would like to take data from "track" to a deep copy so that I don't loose   scope over the data withing that struct */

}
```

In an associated API written in C, there are the following two lines of code that I am forced to use:

```
 typedef void (*vtrCallback)(vtrTextTrack *track, void *calldata);
 int vtrInitialize(const char *inifile, vtrCallback cb, void *calldata);
```

Here is the header of my class:

```
 #include <vtrapi.h>
 #include <opencv.hpp>

 class TextDetect {
const char * inifile;
vtrImage *vtrimage;
int framecount;
 public:
TextDetect();
~TextDetect();
static void vtrCB(vtrTextTrack *track, void *calldata);
int vtrTest(cv::Mat);
bool DrawBox(cv::Mat&);

  };


  TextDetect::TextDetect() : inifile("vtr.ini")
  {
if (vtrInitialize(inifile, vtrCB /*run into problems here*/, NULL) == -1)
    std::cout << "Error: Failure to initialize" << std::endl;
vtrimage = new vtrImage;
framecount = 0;

  }

  void TextDetect::vtrCB(vtrTextTrack *track, void *calldata) /*acts as a callback*/
 {
/*specifically would like to take data from "track" to a deep copy so that I don't loose   scope over the data withing that struct */

 }
```

Comment: Are you interested in something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16785/Thunking-in-Win32-Simplifying-Callbacks-to-Non-sta?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your precise situation, but here is the standard idiom for wrapping a C++ method into a C callback API:

```
/*regular method*/
void TextDetect::vtrCB(vtrTextTrack *track)
{
   // do all the real work here
}

/*static method*/
void TextDetect::vtrCB_thunk(vtrTextTrack *track, void *data)
{
   static_cast<TextDetect *>(data)->vtrCB(track);
}
```

and then, assuming the function that should call `vtrInitialize` is also a `TextDetect` method, you write the call like this:

```
   vtrInitialize(inifile, TextDetect::vtrCB_thunk, static_cast<void *>(this));
```

Comment: vtrInitialize is a 3rd part api. Does that make a difference when you use `static_cast<void *>(this)`?

Comment: It shouldn't.  `vtrInitialize` doesn't *do* anything with its third argument, it just passes it to `vtrCB_thunk`, so both of the casts are in your code.

Comment: Your help was spot on.  Thank you.