# Accessing variable outside scope of a callback c++

Tags: c++, callback, scope, static

I have been beating my head around this issue of static versus non-static, callback functions, function pointers, etc...  My goal is to access data of a struct outside the scope of my callback interface.  I am trying to do this within my class called TextDetect.  I thought I was on track when I asked this question: [Avoiding a static member function in c++ when using a callback interface from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513071/avoiding-a-static-member-function-in-c-when-using-a-callback-interface-from-c)
However, I still can't access the data without losing scope over the data that I am most interested.  At runtime, I get "Access violation reading location ..."  I'll point it out below where it fails.
I implemented the answer to my previous question as the following class, shown entirely (Note: vtrInitialize is part of a 3rd party api code **int vtrInitialize(const char *inifile, vtrCallback cb, void *calldata);**):

```
 class TextDetect {
     const char * inifile;
     vtrImage *vtrimage;
     int framecount;
 public:
     TextDetect();
     ~TextDetect();
     void vtrCB(vtrTextTrack *track);
     static void vtrCB_thunk(vtrTextTrack *track, void *calldata);
     int vtrTest(cv::Mat);
     bool DrawBox(cv::Mat&);
     vtrTextTrack *texttrack;
 };

 TextDetect::TextDetect() : inifile("vtr.ini")
 {
      if (vtrInitialize(inifile, vtrCB_thunk, static_cast<void *>(this) ) == -1) 
         std::cout << "Error: Failure to initialize" << std::endl;
         vtrimage = new vtrImage;
  }


  int TextDetect::vtrTest(cv::Mat imagetest)
  {
    /*store image data in an image structure*/
  }

   void TextDetect::vtrCB(vtrTextTrack *track)
   {
     /*send data to command line from callback */
```

I've tried copying the data I need a variety of ways and nothing works (this code is a continuation from above):

```
     //texttrack = track;
     //texttrack = new vtrTextTrack (*track);
     memcpy(texttrack,track,sizeof(*track));
     //vtrTextTrackFree(track); 

    }
  void TextDetect::vtrCB_thunk(vtrTextTrack *track, void *calldata)
  {
       static_cast<TextDetect *>(calldata)->vtrCB(track);
  }
```

This is the member function were I want the data to be used.  Texttrack is public member so I might need it outside my class as well (this code is a continuation from above):

```
  bool TextDetect::DrawBox(cv::Mat& tobeboxed)
  {
```

And I get the access violation error at runtime here at this line of code (this code is a continuation from above):

```
  if (texttrack->best->ocrconf > 90)
     {
        /*do some more stuff*/
   }
  }
```

Comment: honestly, is really that much code necessary to depict your problem?

Comment: The problem you have in the form it is written is difficult to understand quickly; perhaps simplifying it will prompt more people to answer.

Comment: Well, your `memcpy` is certainly an error: it cannot possibly copy all of `track`, as you obviously have pointers in the `track`, which will be copied, but not what they point to. I can easily imagine, that the `track` data do not exist outside the callback.

Comment: @user What Torsten Robitzki said.

Comment: Interesting... track does have pointers within that structure.  Do you know any work around? How can I get at that data beyond the callback?

Comment: I cut down on the info.  Is that helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I'm understanding this correctly.

It seems to me that the problem is trying to copy those vtrTextTrack structs improperly.
This:

```
//texttrack = track;
```

just copies the pointer. If the owner of the struct (probably the caller of the callback function) destroys/deletes the vtrTextTrack, then you're holding on to an invalid pointer.

This one:

```
memcpy(texttrack,track,sizeof(*track));
```

will copy all the members of the vtrTextTrack, but will not copy what's being pointed to by it's member pointers (e.g. `texttrack->best`). Again, if the owner destroys/deletes the track, then you're holding on to invalid pointers.

And since

```
//texttrack = new vtrTextTrack (*track);
```

didn't work, I'm guessing that vtrTextTrack doesn't provide a copy constructor.

As for a workaround, first check if your third party library provides a function to copy these structs. If that's not the case (could this be by design?), then you may have to implement one yourself. This might be hard because there might be all kinds of internals that you don't know about. If you don't need the whole vtrTextTrack, I'd say define another struct and store only the information you need. Something along the lines of

```
SomeType* bestCopier(SomeType* src)
{
     SomeType* temp;
     /* copy over struct */
     return temp;
}

Foo* fooCopier(Foo* src)
{
    /*...*/
}

struct myTextTrack 
{
public:
    myTextTrack(vtrTextTrack* src)
    {
        //copy over stuff
        m_best = bestCopier(src->best);
        m_foo = fooCopier(src->foo);
    }

private:
    /* the members you care about*/
    SomeType* m_best;
    Foo * m_foo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Let me play with your idea and report back.

Comment: As I play with this two question come up. 1) best in the APIs vtrTextTrack is a pointer. Does that mean that SomeType in your above example should be SomeType * best? Does that change anything in your example? 2) SomeType is actually another struct (in C not C++). Does that mean I have to create my own copy constructor for that struct that is declared in your above example?  SomeType has pointers as well.

Comment: You're right, my code wasn't quite right. I made some changes, and it's just one way you could approach it. Since these are all C structs and there is no copy constructor, you may just have to write a copy function for each part. It won't be fun, that's for sure. Do you need to keep the actual vtrTextTrack struct, or just certain info inside it? Because the latter would be easier. Also, it might be worth it to take a step back and think whether there's another way of accomplishing the same thing that fits better with the model of the 3rd party library.

Comment: Your help has been great.  It works as you said.  I dug deep through the struct to go beyond the pointer and it copied.  Thank you.